Apply Prisma Migrations to Multiple Environments with Kubernetes
I’m working on a Nextjs application using Prisma as ORM, where the Docker container is built via GitHub Actions and deployed to Kubernetes across environments for multiple user organizations (let’s call them "clients").
My question is : How would you apply Prisma migrations to the client databases during upgrades?
Prisma's documentation suggests applying migrations through the CI/CD pipeline. However, in our case, this is not an option because:

The client databases are neither known nor accessible at build time.
The environments may not be upgraded simultaneously, making build-time migration inappropriate.

With other ORMs like Python/Alembic, I’ve handled this by integrating migrations into Kubernetes deployment args to overwrite the Docker entrypoint (which is fine as long as several containers don't try to start concurrently).
apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: container-name
      args:
        - bash
        - -c
        - alembic upgrade heads && uvicorn app.main:app ...

However, in the case of Prisma, with a multi-stage build that only embeds the Prisma client (discarding build-time dependencies), this approach isn’t viable. Embedding the entire Prisma library would result in a bloated container image.
Should migrations be deployed separately via a dedicated Job? Or do you recommend other approaches?

This is how I did it in one of my projects:

Inside the multi-staged Dockerfile, ensure the prisma folder is COPY-ed over into the final stage:

# Assuming /builder/ is WORKDIR of the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /builder/prisma ./prisma


Modify the package.json file to call prisma migration command inside the start command:

  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "npx prisma migrate deploy && next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },


Make the CMD command in Dockerfile call npm start:

CMD ["npm", "start"]

If you prefer to use an init container to perform the migration, just modify step 2 to bind something like npm migrate script to the npx prisma migrate deploy command and override the args of that init container to call npm migrate instead of npm start:
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "migrate": "npx prisma migrate deploy",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },


Thanks for the detailed answer. I think I'll stay with the single container approach. Creating a separate init container creates strong constraints on the upgrade and restart order between containers.

It works; however, I get this warning during the prisma migrate deploy step:
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: prisma@5.22.0
